# Sale on now, On sale now, Sale now on

Tags: grammar

I found a phrase "Sale on now" from a website. I think it is to tell customers that some products are currently offered at the lower prices. But what is the correct order of saying this. I personally think it should say "On sale now" but I also found someone saying "Sale now on".

Which one is correct?

Thank.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the country, but I think that "sale now on" is slang regardless. It's also not a direct synonym of "on sale now," which refers to an object or set of objects that are on sale, such as "these shirts are now on sale."."Sale now on" seems like a way of saying "a sale is going on," referring to the existence of the discounts/the sale.

Comment: _Sale now on_ is idiomatic in British English; you might see it written up outside a shop to indicate that they are offering some of their stock at bargain prices. _On sale now_ just means that the item is available to purchase, with no implication as to price.